# Staggered install of pip requirements on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I have a Flask app running on Heroku.

Installing from `requirements.txt` is failing as later packages depend on the on the earlier ones to be installed first.

Is there a way to stagger these installs, or to run a bash script to install one at a time when the dyno is spun up?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so a workaround:

Remove the latter package in the `requirements.txt` file which depends on the earlier one. Deploy to heroku so the earlier one is installed. Then add back the package you removed and deploy again. Huzzah!